# Are students considered as adults or as children for reproducing in Banished?

Tags: banished

I wonder when I spot two different gender students in my settlement, if I build a new house, will they move in and start to reproduce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Students do marry BUT one of the couples must be a worker. Actually it makes sense because how two students are going to provide for a household?

In conclusion, if all your workers are married and you only have students that are of reproduction age, do not build a new house until one of the students graduate.

**Addendum:** Note that the previous paragraph is very important. Because if you build homes earlier, some couples may break up and one parent, maybe along with some of the children, move to this new home.

This is an undesirable thing because this effectively means using up more food and firewood for +1 home. Building your homes as described in the second paragraph, you can "force" couples to live in the same house.

However, I don't know if "forcing" to live couples at the same house in this way have any adverse effects on their happiness.

Comment: Citizens in banished don't eat more when they break up.  The relatively small movement of food from your surplus stores to a home's pantry will be offset when the citizen dies and laborers clear their home.  Only Fuel is expended on a per-occupied-house basis.

Answer (score 2):

Students do marry, move in, and have children.

Comment: But in my game they never do. Is it possible that some people will prefer not to marry and have children?

Comment: @utku Citizens of Banished seem to be much like folks in the real world.  Given sufficient available housing, couples will break up & live alone and young adults will often live as single parents.  The only thing that seems to prevent breeding is living at home with the parents. (unlike the real world?)